# Find $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

What is the value of $\sqrt{(-1)^2} ;$ 1 or -1?

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt 1= 1 $

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = {((-1)^2)}^{1/2} = (-1)^1 = -1$

Or is it both?

Comment: By definition, $\sqrt x$ denotes the non-negative solution to $z^2=x$.  Thus, for example, we always have $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: It is the first. The equality ${((-1)^2)}^{1/2} = (-1)^1$ is incorrect.

Comment: @lulu  for real $x$.

Comment: To @TheSilverDoe's point: there is a discrepancy between sqrt and $1/2$ power. These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

By definition, if $x\in \mathbb R$, then
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $z$ is a non-zero complex number and $m,n$ are positive integers prime to each other, then $(z^{1/n})^m=(z^m)^{1/n}$

If gcd$(m,n)\neq 1$ then $(z^{1/n})^m\neq (z^m)^{1/n}$, in general.

**Example:**  Let $z=i,m=4,n=6.$ Then $(z^{1/n})^m=(i^{1/6})^4 \qquad \qquad \;\;=\cos {4r\pi+\pi \over 3}+i\sin {4r\pi+\pi \over 3}$ where $r=0,1,2,...,5$. It has three distinct values. But $(z^m)^{1/n}=1^{1/6}=\cos {2k\pi \over 6}+i\sin {2k\pi \over 6}$, where $k=0,1,...5$. It has six distinct values.

In your question $\sqrt {(-1)^2}=\sqrt 1=1$

[$\sqrt$ is the positive square root function].

Comment: Are you trying to earn reputation?